# Django keeps on resetting my fileinput in a mutipart form

Tags: django, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am using a multipart form to upload some sql file in django 1.8 with python3.

When i fill out everything and submit the form the fileinput seems to reset and gives validation error, that the file has to be set before submit (which is correct) but i dont't understand why it's resetted.

Here is the template:

```
<form method='post' name="edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }} {{ field.errors }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    ...

</form>
```

And the the django form:

```
class TaskBlockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=DemoUser.objects.all())
    input = forms.FileField(label=_('Tables'))

def is_valid(self):

    valid = super(TaskBlockForm, self).is_valid()

    if not valid:
        return valid

    # check if name field is unique
    table = None

    try:
        table = TaskBlock.objects.get(name=self.cleaned_data['name'])
    except:
        self._errors['no_table'] = 'Table does not exist'

    if table:
        self.errors['name'] = 'This tablename is already in use.'
        return False

    return True

class Meta:
    model = TaskBlock
    # use following model fields
    fields = ('name', 'description',)
```

the output in the browser:

[image: Rendered in the browser]

Comment: You absolutely should not be overriding `is_valid()`. Define `clean()` instead.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.
I forgot to pass the request.FILES to the Form in views.py as follows:

```
form = TaskBlockForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Now it works as expected